# Confused about the package_dir and packages settings in setup.py

Tags: python, distutils

Here is my project directory structure, which includes the project folder, plus
a "framework" folder containing packages and modules shared amongst several projects
which resides at the same level in the hierarchy as the project folders:

```
Framework/
    package1/
        __init__.py
        mod1.py
        mod2.py
    package2/
        __init__.py
        moda.py
        modb.py
    
My_Project/
    src/
        main_package/
             __init__.py
             main_module.py
    setup.py
    README.txt
```

Here is a partial listing of the contents of my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(packages=[
        'package1',
        'package2.moda',
        'main_package'
    ],
    package_dir={
        'package1': '../Framework/package1', 
        'package2.moda': '../Framework/package2', 
        'main_package': 'src/main_package'
    })
```

Here are the issues:

1. No dist or build directories are created
2. Manifest file is created, but all modules in `package2` are listed, not just the `moda.py` module
3. The build terminates with an error:

   > README.txt: Incorrect function

I don't know if I have a single issue (possibly related to my directory structure) or if I have multiple issues but I've read everything I can find on distribution of Python applications, and I'm stumped.

Comment: FTR distributing only a submodule from a package (package2.moda) is not a feature supported by any packaging tool I know, and it will also cause import trouble at run-time.

Answer (score 16):

If I understand correctly, the paths in `package_dir` should stop at the parent directory of the directories which are Python packages. In other words, try this:

```
package_dir={'package1': '../Framework', 
             'package2': '../Framework', 
             'main_package': 'src'})
```

Comment: It seems that I have to specify it as 

    {'package1': '../Framework/package1',
    'package2': '../Framework/package2'}

Otherwise I get errors complaining that there is no __init__.py file found.

I also keep getting an error as stated above - the output ends with 


    error: My_Project-1.0\README.txt: Incorrect function

If I remove the README.txt file, I get a warning that it's missing, but still get an error:


    error: My_Project-1.0\Setup.py: Incorrect function

Comment: With this `package_dir`, should you execute `import package1` and `package2`?

Comment: Yes, that’s the goal.

Comment: @SteveSawyer Were you able to solve this issue? I am in a similar boat. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I've had a similar problem, which was solved through the specification of the root folder and of the packages inside that root.

My package has the following structure:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── common
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── persistence.py
        ├── schemas.py
        └── utils.py
```

The *setup.py* contains the *package_dir* and *packages* line:

```
package_dir={"myutils": "src"},
packages=['myutils.common'],
```

After running the `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and installing the **.whl** file, the package can be called using:

```
import myutils.common
```

Comment: More info can be found at: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: small fix: it should be `python setup.py bdist_wheel`  (miss spell in "whell")