# Is it possible to give multiple source dir to find_packages() using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a python project which want to be distributed by using setuptools.

I want to use `find_packages()` function. The python source packages located in multiple directory:

```
proj
  +--src1
  |    +--pkg1
  |    |    +-- (__init__.py and sources)
  |    +--pkg2
  |    |    +-- (__init__.py and sources)
  +--src2
       +--pkg3
       |    +-- (__init__.py and sources)
       +--pkg4
            +-- (__init__.py and sources)
```

If I use `find_packages('proj/src1')` the pkg3 and pkg4 wont be packed into the distribution.

If I use `find_packages('proj')` the no packages will be listed at all.

Is it possible to use multiple source directories and `find_packages()` together?

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155804/confused-about-the-package-dir-and-packages-settings-in-setup-py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find_packages()` returns a list. You can call it a few times and combine the lists:

```
find_packages('proj/src1') + find_packages('proj/src2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not build the package list yourself?

```
packages=[pkg for subdir in os.listdir('proj')
          if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('proj', subdir))
          for pkg in find_packages(os.path.join('proj', subdir))]
```