# trouble with check-manifest - python module deployment

Tags: python, python-module

```
A:\repos\BinaryCounters> check-manifest --create
```

I run the above command, and it gives me this error:

```
some files listed as being under source control are missing:
  BinaryCounters.py
['c:\\program files\\python36\\python.exe', 'setup.py', 'sdist', '-d', 'C:\\Users\\pk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\check-manifest-jdugbjbj-sdist'] failed (status 1):
running sdist
running egg_info
error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist or is not a directory
```

however my project structure looks correct:
[image: file structure]

and my setup.py looks like this:

```
setup(

     ..
     py_modules=["BinaryCounters"],
     package_dir={'': 'src'},
     ..
)
```

I'm unsure what I could have missed.

Comment: Looks like the problem was related to `package_dir` parameter. Related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155804/confused-about-the-package-dir-and-packages-settings-in-setup-py

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help someone else - but the issue I encountered was that I had removed a file in the git directory which `check-manifest` was looking for, i.e. a `exampleTest.py` file. To solve this I ensured that my changes were committed in git first, before retrying:

```sh
# Check changes
git status
# -> Shows exampleTest.py has been deleted

# Submit deletion change
git add tests/exampleTest.py && git commit -m "removed exampleTest.py" && git push

# Retry check-manifest --create
check-manifest --create
```