# How to install from a private git repo from a pip requirements file?

Tags: python, git, pip

I can install from a private git repo perfectly by running:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@example.com/myaccount/myrepo.git@tagname
```

My Python package has a main folder called "mypackage", and after running this command, my virtual environment has that folder in `<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.

How do I run this same equivalent command from a pip requirements file?

If I create a requirements.txt file containing:

```
git+ssh://git@example.com/myaccount/myrepo.git@tagname
```

and run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

it succeeds and installs the packages, but it installs it into `<venv>/lib/python3.9/src/mypackage` and it contains my entire repo code, not just the main source file that my setup.py says should be exported.

How do I fix this so the install functions identically to the regular pip install command?

I also tried this line:

```
-e git+ssh://git@example.com/myaccount/myrepo.git@tagname#mypackage
```

but that also installs to the "src" folder inside my virtualenv.

Comment: Found another topic which worked for me with the same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155804/confused-about-the-package-dir-and-packages-settings-in-setup-py