# Import locally installed python package from elsewhere

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

Yet another stupid question about Python packaging. I've searched stackoverflow but am unable to find an answer, or, the answers I find do not work.

The task: Load a package, locally installed (with or without the -e editable flag), from another .py file somewhere else, or from python on the command line.

The setup:

```
test-proj1
└── run.py

test-proj2
├── setup.py
├── test-proj2
│   ├── proj2_functions.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

My setup.py in `test-proj2` (top directory):

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="test_proj2",
    version="1.0.0",
    description="...",
    long_description="...description",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    package_dir={"": "test-proj2"},
    packages=find_packages(where="test-proj2"),
)
```

In `test-proj2` (top directory), I've run `python3 -m pip install .` , or `python3 -m pip install -e .`  (tried both, none worked).

After this, from the pip in the virtualenv I am using (`which pip` shows the right path, `which python` as well), `pip freeze | grep test-` shows the package as installed.

- From `test-proj1/run.py`, or just python opened in a console, how can I import

  a) just the package `test_proj2` (it's okay if it is empty)?
  b) the function `add` in `proj2_functions.py` ?

I have tried adding the absolute path to `test-proj2` to the Pythonpath, not even then can I import `test_proj2` or `test_proj2.test_proj2`. The error message is:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_proj2'

---

My mental model is that installing the package, with or without -e, makes it available to the Python binary I used when calling `python -m pip install ...`. Or is it a problem with `-` in the directory names? I read that `-` can just be replaced by `_` when importing (and all sorts of other equivalent names could be used as well).

I'll try not using packages for now, but it really bugs me that I cannot get this to run.

Comment: You will need to name your Python modules and packages in a way that makes them valid Python identifiers to be able to use them with `import`. As I see it, you have `test-proj2`; you can't do `import test-proj2`. (To be clear, the `name=` you specify in `setup.py` doesn't affect imports in any way.)

Comment: "I read that - can just be replaced by _ when importing (and all sorts of other equivalent names could be used as well)." You've read wrong.

Comment: And – sorry for the comment spam – you shouldn't use `setup.py` anymore; use e.g. [hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/).

Comment: When somebody wrote that `-` could just be replaced with `_`, they probably meant that you need to rename it and things will work, rather than Python figuring it out on its own.

Comment: @AKX thanks a lot - I've read this about the "name" parameter in setup.py, I wasn't aware that that name has no importance to how you import the package... Here is what I read: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#setup-args

Comment: Why is there that name parameter in the first place, I wonder...

Comment: @dasWesen See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758

Comment: Also you could remove `package_dir={"": "test-proj2"},`, it's for src-layout, not your case. See an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705254/7976758 and the docs at https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html